# How to include CodeMirror in Meteor's summernote?

Tags: meteor, codemirror, summernote

I included the CodeMirror libraries in the head of my layout and initialize summernote with codemirror option, but meteor summernote is still not using CodeMirror.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the libraries of codemirror have to load before Summernote's libraries. Make sure Summernote's dependencies load before Summernote's ones. In Meteor, we have to change the order of packages in the package file. Putting the Summernote package after the CodeMirror package helps.